# Strategy for game with probability

Tags: probability

Two people: person $A$ and person $B$ are playing a game.
Person $A$ picks two different natural numbers $x$ and $y$.  He places each number inside an envelope.

Then person $B$ has to pick one envelope and open it.
After he looks at the number inside the envelope, he has a choice, either stay with the same envelope or switch, while he doesn't know what is the second number.

The goal is for person $B$ to find a strategy in which he will find the bigger number with a probability bigger than $\large\frac{1}{2}$.

This is a riddle friend of mine gave me. I am not even sure it is possible. With a probability of $\large \frac{1}{2}$ is easy, you just choose randomly.

Do you have any idea how to do it or a hint you could give me?

Comment: Since we cannot even know by what distribution $A$ picks the numbers, ... "Swap if you see $1$, keep otherwise" would solve the problem if the probability of $A$ picking $1$ is nonzero

Comment: Very similar to the [two envelopes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_envelopes_problem).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you open an envelope and see a number $n$. You need to decide whether to switch or stay. If you always decide the same way for any given value of $n$ then your opponent can, if they know your strategy, always reduce your winning chance to 50%: they just choose two numbers for which you will do the same thing.

So when you see $n$ you must use a random strategy: switch with some probability $p_n$, and stay with probability $1-p_n$. Now exactly the same argument means that all the values of $p_n$ for the different $n$ must be different, since otherwise your opponent can choose numbers $m$ and $n$ with $p_m=p_n$, holding you to 50%.

One you've got this far, it makes sense that if $m<n$ then $p_m>p_n$, and in fact any sequence of probabilities that satisfy this will work. If your opponent picks $m$ and $n$ then you will end up with $n$ with probability $\frac12p_m+\frac12(1-p_n)>\frac12$. (For example, you might use $p_n=1/n$.)